# from javascript to jsf backing bean

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have an orderList populated with some objects. This kind of objects have some fields ingluding a field code.

I want to delete multiple selected options from the orderlist when I pres a Delete button. In order to achieve this, I wrote a javascript function that gets the codes of selected items in the orderlist and sets the value of an inputText (that latter will be inputHidden).

```
function isDelBtnClicked() {
   var selectedLi = $('.ui-state-highlight');
   var codes = "";
   var inputHiddenCodes = document.getElementById('form:inptHCodes');
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedLi.length; i++) {
        codes += selectedLi[i].attributes[1].nodeValue + ";";
   }
   inputHiddenCodes.value = codes;
}
```

**isDelBtnClicked()** sets the value of the inputText below:

```
<h:inputText id="inptHCodes"
             value="#{questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.selectedInputCodes}" />
```

I have a method removeSelctedChoices that should iterate on the list of objects displayed in orderlist and remove those that have the code that the  processes the value of an inputText. So, the method should split the inputText's value by ";", process, and delete the elements containing the current code.

Now, I have to find a way to save the inputText's value that is set by the javascript function to my backing bean.

I tried:

```
 <h:inputText id="inptHCodes" value="#{bean.selectedInputCodes}">
```

thinking that the value="#{bean.selectedInputCodes} will sett the selectedInputCodes inthe backing bean. But no result, selectedInputCodes is null;

I tried:

```
<h:inputText id="inptHCodes" value="#{bean.selectedInputCodes}" >
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{bean.inptHChoicesListener}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

thinking that when the initial value of inputText will change with the selected items codes, the inputHChoiceListener will be triggered.

```
public void inptHChoicesListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
 UIInput uiinput = (UIInput) abe.getSource();
 selectedInputCodes = uiinput.getValue().toString();
}
```

The selectedInputCodes is still null.

The Delete button:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="remove" onclick="isDelBtnClicked()">
    <p:ajax event="click" update="choices" 
            listener="#{bean.removeSelctedChoices}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

So, the big question is how can I get the value of the inputTextComponent when clicking the commandButton?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I see lots of strange constructs that when trying to workaround make things only more complex. Take a normal commandButton like in the PrimeFaces showcase, use a normal inputText and put ajax inside it and. Your 'type="button" with an ajax listener inside and and an onclick looks weird to me

Comment: I have edited the post to be clearer.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the value of the component having the id="inptHCodes" (the inputText) into my backing bean when I call the removeSelctedChoices() (the listener of the commandButton)?

Comment: Why do you try to implement what is already part of the orderlist?  Selection, getting the values server side in a list etc...

Comment: Tell me how can I delete the multiple selected items then, because I don't know how. I am working with this component for the first time. You know, you helped me to add elements.

Comment: Remove them from the list that  backs the orderlist and update the orderlist

Comment: Then, how can I remove multiple selected with only one button? "Remove them from the list that backs the orderlist and update the orderlist" is what I am trying, that I have posted above. I got the codes from all the selected items, not one by time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124239/discussion-between-nelly-junior-and-kukeltje).

Comment: Use ajax selection on the orderlist, or even normal multiple selection. Keep that in a list servers side and when pressing your button, remove the selected items from the list that backs the orderList